# How to keep the div and label in the same row?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

This is what I wish to achieve: display a message next to an input box.

[image]

However, when the message is too long the whole thing goes under the input box.

[image]

**css**

```
.data-form{
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    line-height: 22.8px;
}
.data {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
}
.form-group {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    // box-sizing: border-box;
}
.data-status {
    display: inline-block;
    color: red;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
.data-label {
    display: inline-block;
}

.form-control {
    width:200px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

**html markup**

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
    <form class='data-form'>
        <div class='data form-group row'>
            <label class='data-label'>
                <span> Add a data code </span>
                <input type='text' name='data' class='form-control'>

                <div class='data-status'>
                   <span class='data-status'>TEST  </span>
               </div>

            </label>

        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

I want to keep the whole error message to the right hand side of the `input` regardless of the length of error text

I have tried

1. 'break-word'
2. various different structure [such as moving the message inside a div which sits at the same level of label](http://jsfiddle.net/kongakong/o338t791/2/).

Unfortunately they do not work.

Here is the code that demonstrated the problem 
 http://jsfiddle.net/kongakong/o338t791/3/

Any suggestion? It uses bootstrap css

Comment: Wait do you want the label to break or not? You seem to be getting answers for both. As is the code in your question *does not* break and long labels go underneath the input field.

Comment: So how you want it to look when it overflows?

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr I have updated the question. The end goal is not to let the text go under the input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the `.data-status` rule to this to remove the `inline-block`:

```
.data-status {
    color: red;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

[Here is a fiddle which shows it in action](https://jsfiddle.net/u50y3tLj/)

[image]

The `inline-block` rule is whats forcing the element to remain in a single line. You can also change it to `display:inline;` but this is the default rule for a `span` element.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I would definitely want to keep the whole status message left to the input box. Not part of it under the input box. Is it possible?

Comment: There is still a break in the second row

Comment: @AnthonyKong Do you mean to keep the whole message right to the field? Yes, it is possible. Check the snippet in my solution.

Answer (score 0):

In the form-control, add a display-inline.

```
.form-control {
    width:200px;
    font-size: 16px;
    display:inline;
}
```

Data status as,

```
.data-status {
    display: inline;
    color: red;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Default comes with form-control is display:block.
This will make span and input inline. Wrap the "Add a data code" within a div.

Here is the complete html and css,

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
    <form class='data-form'>
        <div class='data form-group row'>
            <label class='data-label'>
                <div>
                <span> Add a data code </span>
                    </div>
                <input type='text' name='data' class='form-control'>

                <div class='data-status'>
                   <span class='data-status'>TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST</span>
               </div>
            </label>

        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

CSS;

```
.data-form{
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    line-height: 22.8px;
}
.data {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
}
.form-group {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.data-status {
    display: inline;
    color: red;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
.data-label {
    display: inline-block;
}

.form-control {
    width:200px;
    font-size: 16px;
    display:inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do some changes in your html code as

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
    <form class="data-form">
    <div class="data form-group row">
    <label class="data-label">
    <div> Add a data code </div>
    <div class="data-status">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="data">
    </div>
    <span class="data-status">TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST </span>
    </label>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

and in your stysheet put

```
.data-status
{
vertical-align: middle;
}
```